# Launch remote PowerShell session using saved ps1 file

Tags: powershell, windows-server-core

I am trying to create a couple of files that I can save on my local desktop to launch PowerShell sessions.

The Windows Server 2008 and Windows Server 2012 are both Server Core installations.

Currently, I can open Powershell and type:

```
Enter-PSSession -computername Win2012SrvCore -credential administrator
```

Using this, I can connect and run commands and everything is great.

**What I have tried to do is:**

Create file called `Win2012SrvCore1.ps1` with the following:

```
$passwd = convertto-securestring -AsPlainText -Force -String MYPASSWORD

$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "administrator",$passwd

$session = new-pssession -computername Win2012SrvCore -credential $cred
```

Create file called `Win2012SrvCore2.ps1` with the following:

```
PowerShell.exe -Command Enter-PSSession -computername Win2012SrvCore -credential administrator
```

Each `ps1` file will launch and close quickly with some red text that I cannot read.

I have tried to add `PAUSE` to each script but that doesn't seem to stop the window from closing.

What I would like to do is create scripts that I can double click and open to the powershell prompt, similar to a saved RDP session.

I have configured ps1 files to execute:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you manually type this in the ISE line by line, command by command?  Do you still get an error?

Comment: I would open up Powershell ISE (Integrated Scripting Environemt) and run the script. This will display the output and allow you to continue troubleshooting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$passwd = convertto-securestring -AsPlainText -Force -String MYPASSWORD

$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "administrator",$passwd

$session = new-pssession -computername Win2012SrvCore -credential $cred
```

Add one more line:

`Import-PSSession $session`

Then save the .PS1 file and create a shortcut to it as `powershell.exe -noexit -File "C:\PS.ps1"`.

Answer (score 12):

add `-noexit'

`PowerShell.exe -noexit -Command Enter-PSSession -computername Win2012SrvCore -credential administrator`

Answer (score 9):

Try saving your commands as a script file and then have your shortcuts use the command-line:

`powershell.exe -noExit <filename.ps1>`

This will have your shortcuts run the specified script file and not exit powershell at the end of the scripts execution, so you can continue to use the window after the session is established.

For this to work you need to make sure the PowerShell execution policy is not Restricted, otherwise no script files can be executed

To check the current execution policy you can use `Get-ExecutionPolicy` and you can either use `Set-ExecutionPolicy` to change the policy permanantly or add the `-ExecutionPolcy` parameter to the powershell command-line to change it for a single session.

More information about execution policies and their impact can be found using the `help about_Execution_Policies` command.